# H2O importFile skiping rows

Tags: r, csv, h2o, skip

How can I skip rows while importing files?? Skip is not an available option on the h2o.importFile comand.

I have used the library h2o and the command:

```
h2o.importFile()
```

Comment: Maybe, you could first read your data in R, and then subset the data.frame as desired. Finally, you could use the `as.h2o()` function for using your data in h2o.

Comment: But this will be very slow

Comment: then, if you have csv or an ASCII files, why not using awk to filter out what you want to remove, and so you can import your file directly? That should be much faster...

Comment: Could you please explain it better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `h2o.importFile()` function does not provide a way of skipping rows upon import.  You have a few options:

1. Import using `h2o.importFile()` and then subset the frame to the rows you want.  Here are [some examples](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-munging/slicing-rows.html) of how to slice rows in an H2OFrame.
2. Import using a different package that will allow you to skip rows and then use `as.h2o()` to convert the data from a data.frame to an H2OFrame.  As noted in the comments above, the `as.h2o()` function can be slow for big datasets, however, you can speed it up by installing the **data.table** package and setting `options("h2o.use.data.table" = TRUE)`.

I'd recommend the first option, but you could try both and see what's faster for your dataset.